# How to implement FIDO2 (WebAuthn) for Android and IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, webauthn

I developed a web app which uses WebAuthn API to authenticate using hardware security keys. It works fine.

I am trying to implement it natively using Flutter with compatibility for both IOS and Android. Are there any libraries or starting point for these platforms? I don't want to use ChromeTabs or SFSafariViewController.

Please advice.

Comment: By native do you mean not involving a web browser at all? If so it's not really `WebAuthn` anymore and you'd be interacting with CTAP2 directly. I'm not sure if the APIs for doing that at even public on iOS. 

Are you using an OAuth2/OIDC backend for this? If so using ASWebAuthenticationSession or Chrome custom tabs is the recommended mechanism according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

For Android, you have their [FIDO2 API](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps). Some example codelabs and implementations already exist:

1. [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/fido2-for-android)
2. [kotlin example](https://github.com/jedrivisser/fido2-android-api-demo)
3. [java example](https://github.com/android/security-samples/tree/main/Fido).

On iOS, however, FIDO2 is only supported inside the Safari browser (not sure about the other browsers) and only since iOS 13.3 ([link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393#133)).

You may consider using the native FIDO2 API on Android and opening Safari on iOS until the underlying platform support is added.

As [@mackie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980197/how-to-implement-fido2-webauthn-for-android-and-ios#comment-109627932) pointed out, however, if you are using FIDO2 in the authentication portion of an OAuth flow, the recommended path is to use a web browser with ASWebAuthenticationSession or Chrome custom tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a browser window to get user authenticated and on successful login use my-app://myapp/auth/succeed=true&token=xyz as redirect url (private-use URI scheme redirects) and before that register that url pattern for your app "my-app" as protocol. Browser will automatically open your app with given redirect url and you must handle that url to put your app in appropriate state...

Answer (score 0):

New option for iOS/MacOS is [Passkeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/public-private_key_authentication/supporting_passkeys).
But it relies on iCloud.

> Passkeys use iCloud Keychain public key credentials, eliminating the
> need for passwords. Instead, they rely on biometric identification,
> such as Touch ID and Face ID in iOS, or a specific confirmation in
> macOS for generating and authenticating accounts.
>
> As the authenticator, your Apple device generates a unique
> public-private key pair for every account it creates on a service. The
> authenticator retains the private key and shares its public key with
> the server, known as the relying party.